# ¿Cómo puedo abrir otra ventana con datatables?

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

¿Existe alguna posibilidad de mostrar en otra página el
`a href='Mantencion_Marca_Tracto_Pdf.php`? Porque al hacer click abre en la misma página, y hasta ahora no he encontrado algo que me pueda facilitar lo que necesito.

```
"columns":[
               {"data": "id_mantencion_tractos_marca"},
               {"data": "patente_tracto"},
               {"data": "empresa_mantencion_marca"},
               {"data": "fecha_mantencion"},
               {"data": "numero_factura_marca", "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
           $(nTd).html("<a href='Mantencion_Marca_Tracto_Pdf.php?id="+oData.id_mantencion_tractos_marca+"'>"+oData.numero_factura_marca+"</a>");
       }
   },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añadiendo la propiedad  target="_blank" a tu etiqueta de enlace , te permitira abrir la pagina en una nueva ventana o pestaña

```
<a href"otraPagina" target="_blank"> ir a otra pagina</a>
```

Te dejo la documentacion de esa propiedad [Etiqueta target](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Answer (score 1):

cambia esto

```html
 $(nTd).html("<a href='Mantencion_Marca_Tracto_Pdf.php?id="+oData.id_mantencion_tractos_marca+"'>"+oData.numero_factura_marca+"</a>");
       }
```

por esto

```html
 $(nTd).html("<a target='_blank' href='Mantencion_Marca_Tracto_Pdf.php?id="+oData.id_mantencion_tractos_marca+"'>"+oData.numero_factura_marca+"</a>");
       }
```

Comment: Gracias estimado